# Разбить строку по 8 бит и перевести

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, вывод, перевод

Дана последовательность из  битов, каждый бит имеет значение 0 или 1. Нужно разделить эту последовательность на байты, по 8 битов в каждом (в последний байт может
попасть меньше битов). После этого нужно распечатать значения всех полученных байтов в
привычной людям десятичной системе исчисления.
*Биты внутри байта записываются в привычном современным компьютерам порядке
little-endian: сначала идут младшие биты, потом старшие.*
В первой строке входного файла записано одно целое число  — количество битов в
последовательности. Во второй строке записано ровно  символов 0 или 1:
значения битов последовательности.
**после второй строки файла символ перевода строки может быть, а может не
быть.**
Мой код представлен ниже. Сколько ни бьюсь с ним - неверный ответ на выходе. Подскажите тупящему новичку, что можно сделать/исправить?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){
    int N, i, v;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int p[N-1];
    for (i=0; i<=N-1; i+=8){
        v=((p[i]*(pow(2,i)))+(p[i+1]*(pow(2,(i+1))))+(p[i+2]*(pow(2,(i+2))))+(p[i+3]*(pow(2,(i+3))))+(p[i+4]*(pow(2,(i+4))))+(p[i+5]*(pow(2,(i+5))))+(p[i+6]*(pow(2,(i+6))))+(p[i+7]*(pow(2,(i+7)))));
        printf("%d", v);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Биты внутри байта записываются в привычном современным компьютерам порядке little-endian: сначала идут младшие биты, потом старшие."  прям выделено ошибочную формулировку. little-endian - это о порядке байтов в более крупных единицах (int к примеру). Тело Вашего цикла как минимум можно переписать. И также нигде не сказано, что результат будет влазить в int.

Comment: Считать **строку**, идти с конца по 8 символов (если считать, что это - нормальное число со старшим разрядом слева, а выводить надо байты от младшего разряда), преобразовывать в число, выводить...

Comment: Вы собираете не по биту, а по 32 бита за раз, каждый инт содержит (в современных компиляторах 4 байта, а в общем зависит от архитектуры процессора), а не 1 бит. sizeof поможет Вам. Учите лучше в начале правильные значения, а не их имитации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t N = 0;
    scanf("%zu", &N);

    size_t num_of_bytes = N / 8 + (N % 8 != 0);
    uint_least8_t* buff = malloc(num_of_bytes * sizeof(uint_least8_t));
    if (!buff)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    int buff_pos = 0;
    int byte = 0, digit_shift = 0, digit = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%1d", &digit);

        byte += digit << digit_shift;
        ++digit_shift;
        if (digit_shift == 8)
        {
            buff[buff_pos] = byte;
            ++buff_pos;
            byte = 0;
            digit_shift = 0;
        }
    }
    if (N % 8 != 0)
        buff[buff_pos] = byte;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_of_bytes; ++i)
        printf("%" PRIuLEAST8 " ", buff[i]);
    free(buff);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Пример ввода:

```
27
11111111 00000001 01010101 011
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/lM8uuZ):

```
255 128 170 6
```

Comment: Спасибо! Хотелось код сделать покороче - получилась белиберда. Тут, видать, главнее качество :)

Answer (score 1):

тихий ужас :)

во-первых вместо `pow(2, i)` лучше использовать `1 << i` - т.е. битовое смещение 1чки вправо - это равносильно возведению в степень 2, только ГОРАЗДО быстрее и не требует подключения дополнительных библиотек

Как бы я сделал алгоритм:

1. перемещаемся в цикле по 8 и накапливаем байт

   ```
    value = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < 8; index ++)
        value += buf[index] << index;
   ```
2. по буферу `p` шел бы с через предыдущий цикл

   ```
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < N) {

        int* buf = (int*)p + pos;

        value = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < 8; index ++)
            value += buf[index] << index;

        pos += 8;
    }
   ```
3. и конечно надо учесть, что на последнем байте может потребоваться менее 8 шагов цикла:

   ```
    const int size = (N - pos >= 8) ? 8 : (N - pos);
   ```

В итоге алгоритм был бы таким:

```
int pos = 0;
while (pos < N) {

    int* buf = (int*)p + pos;

    const int size = (N - pos >= 8) ? 8 : (N - pos); 

    value = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < pos; index ++)
        value += buf[index] << index;

    // тут выводим value в требуемом виде

    pos += 8;
}
```

Конечно считаем, что в массиве `p` уже записаны числа

Если в нем записаны буквы, тогда надо так:

```
int pos = 0;
while (pos < N) {

    char* buf = (char*)p + pos;

    const int size = (N - pos >= 8) ? 8 : (N - pos); 

    value = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < pos; index ++) {
        const int bit = (buf[index] == '0') ? 0 : 1;
        value += bit  << index;
    }

    // тут выводим value в требуемом виде

    pos += 8;
}
```

P.S.

если я не перепутал бигэниан и литлэндиан, иначе придется так:

```
value += buf[index] << (7 - index);
```

Comment: Наверное я чего-то не понимаю, это имитация сбора по биту байтов (то есть действительно 8битных в этом случаи) 4байтовыми интами ? Зачем ломать мозг такими задачами((

Comment: ну возможно обучающие задачи на умение составлять алгоритмы и понимать базу языка

Comment: Спасибо большое :) При тестировании подошел первый вариант. Эффективность пока что не получается оседлать, но будем стараться